# Preserve param when using router link

Tags: angular

Is there is a way to achieve a route change while keeping the end of the current url ? Example :

I have a route definied like that : /detail/:user-name/:activity-name
I would like to be able using the RouterLink directive to achieve the following action :

Move from /detail/tom/resume -->  /detail/alex/resume (update the user-name param but keeping intact the activity-name param)

Thanks you.

Comment: Hey, did you find any workaround for this? Answers are not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this (not tested) :

```
activityName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('activity-name');
detail = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('detail');

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

```html
<a [routerLink]="[detail, 'tom', activityName]">Tom details</a>
<a [routerLink]="[detail, 'alex', activityName]">Alexdetails</a>
```

Comment: Might work but I'm searching a solution using only directive inside the template